# Xapian search terms which exceed the 245 character length: InvalidArgumentError: Term too long (> 245)

Tags: django, django-haystack, xapian

I'm using Xapian and Haystack in my django app. I have a model which contains a text field that I want to index for searching. This field is used to store all sorts of characters: words, urls, html, etc.

I'm using the default document-based index template:

```
text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
```

This sometimes yields the following error when someone has pasted a particularly long link:

```
InvalidArgumentError: Term too long (> 245)
```

Now I understand the error. I've gotten around it before for other fields in other situations.

My question is, **what's the *preferred* way to handle this exception?**

It seems that handling this exception requires me to use a prepare_text() method:

```
def prepare_text(self, obj):
    content = []      
    for word in obj.body.split(' '):
        if len(word) <= 245:
            content += [word]
    return ' '.join(content)
```

It just seems clunky and prone to problems. Plus I can't use the search templates.

How have you handled this problem?

Comment: Can you post your indexes file and document template

Answer (score 0):

I think you get it right. There's a patch on inkscape [xapian_backend](https://github.com/inkscape/xapian-haystack) fork, inspired from xapian omega project.

I've done something like you've done on my project, with some trick in order to use the search index template:

```
# regex to efficiently truncate with re.sub
_max_length = 240
_regex = re.compile(r"([^\s]{{{}}})([^\s]+)".format(_max_length))

def prepare_text(self, object):

    # this is for using the template mechanics
    field = self.fields["text"]
    text = self.prepared_data[field.index_fieldname]

    encoding = "utf8"
    encoded = text.encode(encoding)

    prepared = re.sub(_regex, r"\1", encoded, re.UNICODE)

    if len(prepared) != len(encoded):
        return prepared.decode(encoding, 'ignore')

    return text
```